# node.js + socket.io + express.js: No connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, express, socket.io

I've been trying to set up a simple socket.io example, but it refuses to work properly. The client runs on Apache2 and should access the node.js-server via the port 3000.

There doesn't seem to be *any* connection and it doesn't seem to matter whether the server's actually running - if the node.js-process is manually stopped on the server (`$ kill xyz`), my client-console throws no errors whatsoever. The exact same result occurs when the app is running (`info  - socket.io started`).

**Server**:

```
// Check dependencies & setup backend
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer(server); // somehow needed? ("Socket.IO's `listen()` method expects an `http.Server` instance as its first parameter.")
var socket = require('socket.io');
// listen @ port 3000 as definied by proxy
server.listen(3000);
// listen w/ socket.io as well
var io = socket.listen(app);

...

// socket.io
// TODO: test, added 01/03/14 
io.set('match origin protocol', true);
io.set('log level', 2);
var clients = io.sockets.clients();
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Connection from ' + client);

    client.emit('news', {
        hello : 'world'
    });

    client.on('event', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**Client**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/socket.io.js" ></script>
        <script>
            try {
                var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3000');
                console.log(io);
                console.log('check 1', socket.socket.connected); // false

                socket.on('connect', function() {
                    console.log('check 2', socket.socket.connected); // not reached
                });

                socket.on('news', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });

            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } finally {
                console.log('fin');
            }
        </script>
```

**Edit 2:**

This code works, but *only locally*. I've even installed Apache 2.4 on the server to ensure I've access to WebSockets (I read somewhere they weren't available in 2.2.x). 
**Server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Client:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/socket.io.js" ></script> 
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('ws://localhost:3000');
            socket.on('news', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                socket.emit('my other event', {
                    my : 'data'
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Your server side code should use `app.listen` (instead of `server.listen`). Your client should use: src="/socket.io/socket.io.js". If you also want to enable websocket for Apache, let find document about it

Comment: I can't simply use socket.io/socket.io.js because the client is stored in /var/www/xyz whereas node.js lies in /var/node. So I simply copied it to the correct location: `$ ./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
$ cp ./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js /var/www/xyz/js`. Websockets seem not to be available in Apache 2.2 and the suggested solution seems to use xhr-polling only. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright guys, I finally have it up and running.

What I did was to migrate my reverse proxy from Apache to a node.js/node-http-proxy-solution. I'm not sure whether this is actually mandatory - but after re-configuring Apache 2.2.2 and even compiling Apache 2.4.7 didn't help, I figured it could be worth a shot. I also switched to a subdomain rather a subdir, as subdirs seems to cause problems in some cases as well. Again, dunno whether this was just a precaution or if this is actually necessary.

What I'm pretty sure is of relevance, however, is how to load the socket.io.js. Since my reverse proxy already forwards requests to the correct (internal) IP, I have to access both socket.io.js as well as the actual Websocket via the TLD w/o ports or ws://.

Long story short, here's the relevant code:

**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

console.log('Express server started on port %s', app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Client**

```
<script src="http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com');
    // , {secure: true}

    socket.on('news', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

**Proxy**

```
var fs = require('fs'), httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

// This will crash as soon as Apache isn't running or the port isn't binded elsewhere
// TODO: fix
var proxyTable = {
    'mydomain.com/subdir' : '127.0.0.1:3000',
    'mysubdomain.mydomain.com' : '127.0.0.1:3000'
};

var httpOptions = {
    hostnameOnly : false,
    router : proxyTable
};

var httpsOptions = {
    hostnameOnly : false,
    router : proxyTable,
    https : {
        key : fs.readFileSync('/path/key', 'utf8'),
        cert : fs.readFileSync('/path/cert', 'utf8')
    }
};

httpProxy.createServer(httpOptions).listen(80); 
httpProxy.createServer(httpsOptions).listen(443);
```

Last but not least, for anyone stumbling upon this via google, versions used:

```
$ npm list --depth=0
myapp@0.0.0 /path/app
├── express@3.4.7
└── socket.io@0.9.16

$ npm list --depth=0
/path/proxy
└── http-proxy@0.10.4
```

Comment: Proxying with nginx is painless and straight forward - latest versions do support WebSockets traffic for proxying by default, so it works with node.js much better and more efficient.
In fact your socket.io connection might be using only XHR-Long-Polling, and not WebSockets, as Apache might not be aware how to deal with WS traffic. Check that point carefully, as in such case you will loose lots of network performance.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I had the same error and your example helped me out!

Answer (score 4):

Please follow examples here: http://socket.io/#how-to-use

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);
app.listen(3000);
```

Additionally this is wrong:

```
io.connect('https://localhost:3000');
```

It should be `ws://localhost:3000/`

Comment: The variable names aside: That seems pretty much identical to my setup and produces the same error.

Comment: Added more. Mate, honestly you are doing too many things there wrong. So please, start from simple examples on http://socket.io/#how-to-use and improve it keeping working. But start simple.

Comment: if you call app.listen(), app will create an internal http server, so `server` and `io` objects are pointless (?)

Comment: app - points to extress. Express it self depends on http. If you call `http.createServer` it will attach http socket to `app` (express), so that next call `socket.listen` will be bound to same http server. And when you call `app.listen` - that guy will use http server we've created earlier. So they all related. Please check default examples from link I've provided in the answer and play with them to understand it more.

Comment: None of these examples even work. The given example for express.js + socket.io refer to Express 2.0, the "new" docs on github are for the unreleased 1.0-version. Seting up a new local project on my Mac w/ `npm install socket.io express` w/ your code for initializing the server (since the official example doesn't work) and their index.html example, all I get is `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8020/socket.io/socket.io.js"`. Also, the use of the ws://-protocol is mentioned nowhere. I'm really confused right now.

Comment: Just had fresh install to check, and followed exact examples from socket.io and express had no issues. You are doing something wrong there, and I cannot tell what, apart of one point - forget about express on git, etc, just follow exact examples from socket.io.